# Start and Stop Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I need to start / stop a Azure virtual machine, but I don't know how I can do this. I don't know anything about Azure or Azure scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options.

The first one is by using the Azure Portal. Click on your VM and at the bottom you should see a button to stop the virtual machine. Starting it again works the same way.

The second option is to use PowerShell. John McCabe has posted a simple script on [his blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/parallel_universe_-_ms_tech_blog/archive/2013/12/16/stop-amp-start-your-vm-s-on-azure-with-powershell.aspx) to do this. The most important functions are `Start-AzureVM` and `Stop-AzureVM`.

If you want to automate this from a developer perspective (which needs a little bit more work than the PowerShell solution) is by using the Azure Management Libraries. Brady Gaster wrote a [great post](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/announcing-the-general-availability-of-the-microsoft-azure-management-libraries-for-net) about it.

The fourth option is to use [Microsoft Azure Automation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/scripts/). There you create runbooks for common tasks. In the samples are scripts already included which can start and stop a VM.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I need a flow to start and stop the VM in a specific hour automatically. The problem in the script about stop (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Stop-Azure-Virtual-Machine-0b1fea97).  I dont know how parameters I need to change and I don't know where are this parameters.Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a Timer-triggered Azure Function to start/stop your VM.  I've provided the steps here:

[Azure Function role like permissions to Stop Azure Virtual Machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838619/azure-function-role-like-permissions-to-stop-azure-virtual-machines/40883318#40883318)

Instead of creating HTTP-triggered Functions, just use Timer-triggered functions instead and edit the PowerShell script content to hardcode the vmname and resourcegroup.

Answer (score -1):

within the Azure portal (I would recommend using the new portal), go into the VM you need, on the dashboard you will see a Stop and Start button, or you can choose to Restart the VM. Hope this helps.