# Running New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment from within a Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I need to wire up a stateless worker ad-hoc to perform a long running job based off a user action that self destructs when its done. I am trying to run New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment from within a PoSh Function App and cannot figure out how to authenticate to Azure from within the PoSh script.

I tried this:

```
$accountName = "myID@mydomain.com"
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force

$cred = new-object PSCredential($accountName, $pwd)

Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName yadda yadda
```

And I get an error message that I need to use an Organization ID (which I am, our Azure AD is federated and we use AD Sync (and SiteMinder w/o WS-* if that matters)):

```
 Add-AzureRmAccount : -Credential parameter can only be used with Organization ID credentials. For more information, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=331007&clcid=0x409 for more information about the difference between an organizational account and a Microsoft account.
```

I tried "Login-AzureRMAccount -Credential $cred" with similar results.

If I do the Add- or Login- cmdlets from a PoSh window on my local machine (which is member joined to AD) with the -Credential flag I get a similar error. If I run the cmdlets without the credential I am prompted for credentials through an interactive ID/PW window (I do not have to enter my password once I type in my ID).

Does anyone know how I can do the authentication? I would be okay with authenticating like above, some sort of pass through credential from our web layer, or even an Option C I don't know about.

Comment: Is it failing on the `Add-AzureRmAccount` or the `New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment` call? If the former, then why make the question about `New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment`?

Comment: Could you logon Azure with interactive ID/PW window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use service principal for authentication.  A sample with instructions can be found here.

[Azure Function role like permissions to Stop Azure Virtual Machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838619/azure-function-role-like-permissions-to-stop-azure-virtual-machines/40883318#40883318)

Comment: I used this to immediately solve the issue at hand so it gets the answer. I wish I could mark two replies as an answer so 4c74356b41 could get points, too.

Answer (score 1):

For that you would need to use Service Principal auth. I don't think there is any sense of copypasting Azure Doc's to this answer, just consult this document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal