# Azure functions & Powershell - unable to Login-AzureRmAccount using certificate

Tags: powershell, azure, x509certificate, azure-resource-manager, azure-functions

I'm building an Azure Function (hosted in app service plan) which will enumerate the assets in my subscription and do something with them.

I have the site set up in such a way that I expect it to work, but Login-AzureRmAccount errors out every time with the notice

`Login-AzureRmAccount : No certificate was found in the certificate store with thumbprint xxxxxxxx`

Here are some relevant pieces:

First I create the cert:

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\currentuser\my        -Subject "cn=$appCommonName" ...etc...
$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())

$aNewApp = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName $AzureADApplicationName -HomePage $AppHomePage -IdentifierUris $appIDUri -CertValue $keyValue -EndDate $cert.NotAfter -StartDate $cert.NotBefore

#export the cert for use future upload to Azure
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "supersecrettpassword" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "Export-cert.pfx" -Password $password
Export-Certificate -Type CERT -Cert $cert -FilePath "Export-cert.cer"
```

Later I provision my Service Principal and give it read access

```
$theSvcPrincipal = New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $ApplicationId 
$testRole = Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ServicePrincipalName $ApplicationId
```

Through the magic of ARM deployments I end up with two app settings in the web site which hosts the azure function : `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` with a value of * and `CertThumbprint` with a value of the thumbprint of the certificate which I've uploaded the the `SSL certificates` area.

Finally, after the ARM template is deployed, I upload the certificate following the instructions from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34730630/31299)

Given all that prep work, I would expect this to work in my function:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -CertificateThumbprint $env:CertThumbprint -ApplicationId $env:ApplicationId -TenantId $env:TenantId
```

but when that line executes, despite my having a certificate in the web site with matching thumbprint, I get the `no cert found wiht matching thumbprint` error.

Comment: In the role assignment script, you are using Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment.  To set the reader role, I believe the cmdlet to use is New-AzureRmRoleAssignment.

Comment: You are correct. That snippet was somewhat off - it's part of my retry code while waiting for the ServicePrincipal  to propagate across Azure

Comment: Do you need to use certificates? Here's an example that does not require certs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838619/azure-function-role-like-permissions-to-stop-azure-virtual-machines/40883318#40883318

Comment: Yes, that's my specific question. Had it working with credentials first, then was asked to change it to use certs

Comment: Can you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly%29?%20This%20will%20help%20us%20investigate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this was a bit embarrassing. It turns out that the ARM template I was using to provision the App Service was using the Dynamic sku:

```
"properties": {
   "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
   "computeMode": "Dynamic",
   "sku": "Dynamic"
}
```

rather than a standard sku:

```
"sku": {
    "name": "B1",
    "tier": "Basic",
    "size": "B1",
    "family": "B",
    "capacity": 1
},
```

Once I switched the two, I was able to access the cert store.

I had seen [this issue discussed on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/538), but dismissed it when a coworker was able to access a client certificate from a function app hosted on a dynamic plan after using the Azure web interface to provision it. I still can't explain how he was able to do it, but I've seen it with my own eyes and poured over the ARM templates from his deployment to verify that he's using the consumption-based model.

Comment: Glad to hear that you are unblocked!